# How to store instances of an integer in an array in a separate variable in C#?

Tags: c#, random

## Goal

A C# program that picks a random number from 1 to 6 and stores it

## Question

Which way to store: the entire sequence or an array of 6 elements with increments to the n-1 index for every hit of n?

## Code

```cs
using System;

namespace DiceProbabilityCalc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] instanceCount = new int[1000];

            for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
            {
                int num = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question

Comment: I'd think that instanceCount is supposed to be an array (or probably Dictionary to reduce confusion) of index/key number 1 to 6, with the value being how many times each of those number appears. Do you actually need to store the complete sequences?

Comment: Try setting the size of `instanceCount` to the number of different random numbers (6) and then incrementing the `instanceCount` for each hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PeterSmith and @Martheen for solving the question in the comments: The array `instanceCount` can be used to store the number of instances instead of the entire sequence. This is the resulting code.

```
using System;

namespace DiceProbabilityCalc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] instanceCount = new int[6];

            for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
            {
                int num = rnd.Next(1, 7);
                instanceCount[num - 1]++;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < instanceCount.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(instanceCount[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: when you create an array, all positions are initialized with the default value, which is 0 for integers

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, thanks. I have edited the answer.